# Undertow: How to control choosing host depends on request body content?

Tags: java, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, undertow

I try to implement my own proxy like this:

```
LoadBalancingProxyClient loadBalancer = new LoadBalancingProxyClient()
        .addHost(new URI("http://localhost:8080"))
        .addHost(new URI("http://localhost:7777"))
        .setConnectionsPerThread(20);

Undertow reverseProxy = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8081, "localhost")
        .setIoThreads(1)
        .setHandler(ProxyHandler.builder().setProxyClient(loadBalancer).setMaxRequestTime(30000).build())
        .build();
reverseProxy.start();
```

I want to have control over choosing proxy server. Depends on request body I want to choose `localhost:8080` or `localhost:7777`

Is it possible in Undertow proxy?

P.S. I am ready to switch to another proxy if it is impossible for undertow

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jetty `org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet` managing a dynamic list of backends.

You can select the target backend overriding:
`org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AbstractProxyServlet.rewriteTarget(HttpServletRequest)`

(I would like to use Undertow only too)